# Why is this DC motor control software not working?

Tags: dc-motor, avr, atmega

I want to control a DC motor with an Atmega16. I have connected a motor driver to port B pins PB0 and PB1. When I try this code, it works great.

```
PORTB &= ~(1<<0); // clockwise 00000010
PORTB |= (1<<1);    
        
_delay_ms(100);
        
PORTB |= (1<<0); // stop 00000011
PORTB |= (1<<1);
        
_delay_ms(100);
```

But when I try to use it with an `if` loop, it won't stop rotating ever. That code looks like this:

```
if ((PINC & (1<<0)) == 0) {
  PORTB &= ~(1<<0);    
  PORTB |= (1<<1);
        
  _delay_ms(200);
                    
  PORTB |= (1<<0);     
  PORTB |= (1<<1);
}
```

It stops only if I use another delay at the end, but that's not what I want. I want to rotate the motor for 200 ms and then stop it.

Can you help me?

Comment: Well what do you have on port C pin 0 and how the pin is configured? If it is low then motor will immediately start a new 200ms cycle. What you might need is just pen and paper to first think what you want to do and then write the code.

Comment: Where is this code? Is this code inside an infinite loop, by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Using busy-delays to achieve timing in an embedded system is almost always wrong/bad design.

Instead you could implement this with a cyclic update triggered by a hardware timer every x ms, which updates the status of PORTB based on certain variables.

Unrelated to your problem, `1 << ...` is always wrong in C. `1` is of type `int` and is signed. Always use `1u << ...` instead.

Comment: Your statement about `1 << ...` is false. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvg4K.png) is what ISO/IEC 9899 has to say about bitwise shift operators.

Comment: @Seir No it isn't. I'm perfectly aware of what the standard says. Specifically it says that: left-shifting a negative integer is UB, shifting data into the sign bit of a signed type is UB, shifting data out-of-range of the promoted type is UB, shifting by a negative count is UB. Avoid most of this by never providing a left operand which is signed! (FWIW check my SO profile, I dare to say I know my way around C slightly better than the average EE.)

Comment: I'm not questioning your skills in C. I'm just pointing out the inaccurate phrasing. You said _"is always wrong"_. The standard says _"it depends"_. In the code examples provided by the OP `1 << ...` will result in defined and expected behavior.

Comment: But the standard says shifting non-negative signed integers that will not overflow should be fine. Why would you need to explicitly make the literal unsigned?

Comment: This is about estabishing safe coding standards instead of writing brittle code. For some `1 << x` is will be fine for x<15 but potentially crash & burn when x is 15. Instead of insisiting on writing brittle, vulnerable code, is it such a chore to write `1u` instead?

Answer (score -1):

My crystal ball says your code is inside an infinite loop. So it runs the motor for 200ms, then it loops and runs the motor for 200ms, then it loops and runs the motor for 200ms, .......